# openssl issue on solaris using c language

Tags: c, unix, gcc, openssl, solaris

I am trying to implement TLS connection to hit a URL with post that also consists of some query string to get some response data. I am trying to use OpenSSL on Solaris but getting some errors. Below i am posting the o/p

```
bash-3.2# /usr/sfw/bin/gcc ssl.c -lkstat -lnsl -lsocket -lresolv -lssl ssl.c:72:23: warning: unknown escape sequence ,
ssl.c:72:23: warning: unknown escape sequence ,    
Undefined first referenced symbol in file BIO_write /var/tmp//cc2qj0DA.o    (symbol belongs to im plicit dependency /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/i386--solaris2.10/3.4    .3/../../../libcrypto .so.0.9.7)    
BIO_free_all /var/tmp//cc2qj0DA.o (symbol belongs to implicit dependency usr/sfw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.3/../../../libcrypto .so.0.9.7)     
IO_ctrl /var/tmp//cc2qj0DA.o (symbol belongs to implicit dependency /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.3/../../../libcrypto .so.0.9.7)    
BIO_read /var/tmp//cc2qj0DA.o (symbol belongs to implicit dependency /usr/sfw/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.3/../../../libcrypto .so.0.9.7)    
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out collect2:     
ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your sources reference `BIO_write`, which is defined in `libcrypto`, not `libssl`, but you only link with `libssl` (through `-lssl`).  Try passing `-lcrypto` as well.

**Note:** OpenSSL 0.9.7 is really, really, really old.  The last upstream release was made in 2005 (!).  You should seriously consider using a more recent version.